# transferring variables between view controllers without getting an error

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LlJF.png)

here is my exact setup of view controllers.The segue's kind is show.and the name is s1
here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var x:String!
    @IBOutlet weak var usr: UITextField!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "s1"){  
            let v = segue.destination as? ViewController222
            v?.ab = usr.text!
        }
    }

    @IBAction func b1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "s1", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

And for the second view controller,ViewController222:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController222: UIViewController {
    var ab:String!

    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        l1.text=ab
    }
}
```

can someone help? My program is crashing although the setup is correct

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: share the crash

Comment: I want to display the content of the text field in the second VC's label when the button is clicked

Comment: here is an  error :   "stringWithFormat:"
    0x103525b47 <+179>: leaq   0xd25e12(%rip), %rdx      ; @"Receiver (%@) has no segue with identifier '%@'".  ps:cant embed images in my post

Comment: @dreamcode - is the segue associated with the button in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes it is associated to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an awful lot of implicitly unwrapped optionals. Things like var ab:String! should be avoided. They just cause problems because they may be nil and you don't know it. Same with force unwrapping a variable. This is bound to cause an issue v?.ab = usr.text!. Best bet is to make use of if let and ?? to unwrap your optionals safely.

Try something like the following.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var x: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var usr: UITextField!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "s1"){  
            if let v = segue.destination as? ViewController222 {
                v.ab = usr.text ?? "" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And second class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController222: UIViewController {
    var ab: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        l1.text = ab
    }
}
```

And then in your storyboard make sure your segue is dragged from the button to ViewController222.

Comment: Just one final question,if i want to execute the facebook graph request,should i put the corresponding code after the 2 conditions,and the name (the graph request result) as a global variable,and the same procedure??thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what the graph request is attempting to do and where you are planning to use the results. If the results are going to be used exclusively in the second view controller then it should be the one to handle the requests. Possibly in the view did load method. If it is going to be used in multiple places it might make sense to create singleton object to handle all the Facebook interaction. A lot of it all depends on how you plan on using the app.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't manually call performSegue(withIdentifier:sender). When you add a segue in Interface Builder, an action is automatically added as well and it is called when you press the button to which the segue is attached. prepare(for segue) is called automatically by the system when you press the button.

Just delete your IBAction and it should work fine.

Comment: There are many cases where it is useful to create a segue in Storyboard which you then want to "manually" call on an action or condition. The problem in this case *might* be due to **both** automatic segue trigger + manual `performSegue()` call, but that doesn't explain or fix the OP's issue.

Comment: Did it.still crashes

Answer (score 0):

OK - I would suggest:

1. Delete your segue from storyboard...
2. Delete the button's IBAction connection from storyboard...
3. Create a new segue from the button to the new view controller...
4. Give that segue the "s1" identifier...

run your app and see if you no longer get the crash.

Note: do **not** re-assign the IBAction to the button.

Comment: Still crashing:/

Comment: hmm... well, I think you need to be a little more detailed in what's going on. If you delete the segue, and delete any connections assigned to the button, then run the app and tap the button, ***nothing*** should happen. Give that a try, and report back.

Comment: true, nothing happened

Comment: ok - now add the segue back in your storyboard, but don't give it an identifier... see if the segue happens without errors (of course, it won't pass the string yet).

Comment: I did it and it crashed

Comment: OK - then either your project files are somehow corrupted, or you've got some other code trying to execute. It clearly is ***not*** related to the segue itself. Are you getting any additional error messages? Any warnings?

Comment: I am seeing the word identifier in red and so many green breakpoints..i am not adding any code

Comment: How are you adding the segue? Ctrl-Click-Drag from the button to an empty space in ViewController222 ? Or some other way?

Comment: By ctrl clicking and dragging from the button to an empty space in view controller 222.i chose show

Comment: Comment out the line `l1.text=ab` in `viewDidLoad()` in your `ViewController222.swift` file. See if it still crashes.